# if else command in data.table to add column

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a data.table with columns "A","C","byvar" and sometimes "B".  I want to summarize it by a variable 'byvar', but only include B if it is present or conditional upon some other criteria.

The following doesn't seem to work, does someone have an idea?

```
dt[, .(
A=sum(A),
if("B" %in% names(dt)) {B=mean(B)},
C=mean(C),
D=sum(A)/C
), by = .(byvar)]
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `B=ifelse("B"%in%names(dt),mean(B),NA)` it'll give you a column with NAs but it is extensible to arbitrary criteria and column names.

```
dt<-data.table(A=runif(100,1,100), C=runif(100,1,100), byvar=rep(letters[1:10],10))
dt[, .(
  A=sum(A),
  B=ifelse("B"%in%names(dt),mean(B),NA),
  C=mean(C),
  D=sum(A)/C
), by = .(byvar)]
```

In running this I get 100 row response because your `D=sum(A)/C` has `C` in it which grabs the original C not the new C and so it gives you 100 rows because there are 100 `C`s.  If you change your definition of `D` to `sum(A)/mean(C)` then it gives what you likely intended.

Edit:

Another way you can do this is to take advantage of the ability to use curly braces in the `J` expression

```
dt[, {checkcol='B'
  prelimreturn=list(A=sum(A),
                    C=mean(C),
                    D=sum(A)/mean(C))
  if(checkcol%in%names(dt)) prelimreturn[[checkcol]]<-mean(get(checkcol))
  prelimreturn}
, by = .(byvar)]
```

Here I set a helper variable called `checkcol` so that we're not putting `"B"` in two places.  Next we make your preliminary result with the columns you know you want.  After that we check if whatever is in `checkcol` exists and if it does we add that column to our prexisting list.  Then the last line in the curly braces is what `data.table` displays which is our `prelimresult` list which may or may not have a "B" column.  You could extend this approach pretty broadly too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), byvar,,.SDcols = patterns("A|B|C")]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the real case is not so generic, would it be possible to have some sort of if statement? I modified the example to make it clearer, thanks!

Comment: @tafelplankje See my update, where `patterns` could help you find the columns you want to summarize.